# Work done by a gas in an expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, work, conventions

1) Consider a gas expanding quasistatically and reversibly from $V_1$ to $V_2$ at constant temperature. I want to calculate the work done. So by convention work done by a system is a negative quantity but in my solutions I have 
$$\delta W=p dV$$
Now $dV>0$ which would imply  that $\delta W >0$ which is confusing me. See I would have thought that it should be 
$$\delta W= -p dV$$
so that $\delta W <0$.

2) Equally confusing is that in my notes I have that for quasistatic process
$$\delta W=\mathbf{f} \cdot d\mathbf{x}$$
and it gives the examples of

(gas) $\delta W=-p dV$

(rubber band) $\delta W=\tau dL$

Why have we just taken $\mathbf{f}$ to be $-p$ for the gas and not $p$?

3) In the first step (isothermal expansion) of the Carnot engine explanation I have that the work done by the gas is
$$W=\int^b_a p dV$$
Now as $dV>0$ this implies that $W>0$ but by convention I would have expected this to be negative?

4) In the same step of the Carnot engine as above but with a rubber band I have the work done by the system is

$$W=-\int^b_a \tau dL$$

but equally I cannot understand why we have a negative sign.

Comment: Does an engine change the convention for work done?

Comment: See the question I've linked. Physicists tend to be casual about the sign convention for work because it's usually obvious from the context.